Can I cook using pre-made seasoned flour
Would pre-made seasoned flour for future use be okay?

Exactly what seasonings are you adding? If they're all dry, the answer is likely to be yes (so long as you don't contaminate it and keep it dry), if wet, even like fresh herbs, probably not.

What are you hoping to achieve? Adding whatever seasoning while you're making whatever it is you're making would require minimum extra effort, given that you have to mix the flour anyway. Meanwhile whatever volatile spices you added would just dissipate and you'd have to keep a bunch of special purpose flour mixes around.... | You can cook with a lot of things, question is whether it's worth it and whether the result will be any good.

Yes. The only concern is perhaps dissipation of flavor and perhaps some natural oils leeching out into the flour, but if you use it regularly I don't see why not. I use preseasoned flour weekly and it works fine.
